# How do I remove the port number from Tomcat urls?

Tags: java, tomcat, dns, tomcat7, linode

Please help!

How do I remove the port number and application name from Tomcat URL's?

I have my domain with GoDaddy and hosting with Linode.com. I installed Tomcat into Linode, uploaded my website files and pointed my domain from GoDaddy to my IP address with Linode but I can't figure out how to remove both the port number and the application name so it is just www.mywebsite.com.

Anyone know how to do this? I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: I think (never setup tomcat before) you have to tell Apache via the conf file to listen on the default Web part (80) instead of what it currently is for .jsp files.

Answer (score 9):

Change Port:

See http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/

in server.xml of your tomcat find

```
<Connector port="8080"
```

and replace with:

```
<Connector port="80"
```

(Similar for HTTPS, Search for 8443 replace with 443)

Context Root:

Simply deploy your web app named ROOT.war and it will be deployed to context root "/"

(my-webapp.war would result in /my-webapp)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I'm still having an issue though, I can't access the site after changing the port to 80...any ideas?

Comment: Update your question with the startup log of your server. Note that on *nix systems you need root privilegs or a workaround to have something listening on ports lower than 1024

Comment: what if I have parrallel of godaddy running on port 80? how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

1.Run the tomcat in the port 80 {HTTP port} 
2.Change the application context path to ROOT and rename the already existed ROOT to some other name

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I'm still having an issue though, I can't access the site after changing the port to 80...any ideas?